# iterate list adding to dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

## objective

loop round a list, if the list does not start with whitespace then use this as a dictionary key, if it does start with whitespace use this as a dictionary value

```
output = '''One
 Two
Three
 Four'''

splitLines = output.splitlines()

dic = {}
lis = []

for i in splitLines:

    if not i.startswith(" "):
        dic[i] = lis
        lis = []

    if i.startswith(" "):
        lis.append(i)
```

The above does not work ...

```
print dic
{'': [], 'Three': [' Two'], 'One': []}
```

what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You want the result to be `{"One: "Two", "Three" : "Four'}`? The one you mentioned is the desired result or the result from the code?

Comment: You are using the pronoun "this" without clear antecedents.

Comment: The two lines which start `dic[i] = lis` appear to be in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this following code,

```
output = '''One
 Two
Three
 Four'''

splitLines = output.splitlines()
dic = {}
dicKey=''
for i in splitLines:
    if not i[0]==(" "):
        dicKey=i
        dic[i] = []
    else:
        dic[dicKey].append(i)

print(dic)
```

Output is like this : `{'One': [' Two'], 'Three': [' Four']}`

**No use of List `lis` here**